# Do all nouns from verbs nominalized by the suffix "-ung" have a female gender?

Tags: grammar, gender, suffix, nominalization

By suffixing verbs with *"-ung"* we can build nouns, e.g.:

> prüfen - Prüfung
>    meinen - Meinung
>   richten - Richtung

All those nouns seem to have a female gender. Is that always true or do we have exceptions from that rule?

Comment: Yes. Exception: springen, der Sprung ;-) **(just kidding)**

Comment: I would not say that -ung is a suffix in Sprung. Instead it is a vovel change since the word base of the verb is spring. see: ich springe, ich sprang, ich bin gesprungen.

Comment: @harper sigh. Of course you're right. Apparently an emoticon plus bold j/k wasn't enough.

Comment: @splattne: My first thought was "der Dung" `:-)`

Comment: Not to talk about Joachim Hornung. :)

Comment: I am not sure about this.  
What about 'Aufschwung', 'Abschwung' and 'Anschwung'?  
All of them are male. The only question is: are they built from verbs? (e.g. aufschwingen)

Comment: @jasperado It's *der Schwung*, but *die Schwingung*.

Comment: @Em1: it's "der Schwung", but this is not a verb suffixed by "-ung". So this shouldn't count as exception.

Comment: @harper Already mentioned in the precedent comments! I just added, that the appropriate word is *Schwingung*. I thought this would be clear enough.

Comment: I find it interesting that the natives don't know this, as it's one of the first things you learn as a foreigner! My teacher added humorously that it was the first and the last time we would come across a rule without an exception in the German language ...

Comment: "Jemanden ins Achtung stellen" - An exception from military language.

Comment: @Stovner Natives don't need rules for the gender of nouns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK this is always true: all nouns ending with suffix "-ung" have female gender. There are [some notes on the conversion verb - noun using that suffix at canoonet.eu](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/ung.html). Furthermore, [elexiko](https://www.owid.de/suche/elex/erweitert) allows for searching for words sharing a certain suffix. The search returned zero matches for nouns ending on "ung" with male or neutral gender; only with gender set to female, elexiko returns matches (73, to be precise). So i assume there are in fact no nouns with other than female gender ending on "ung".

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is true. You have also some suffixes that require a male gender.

See: http://deutsch.lingo4u.de/grammatik/nomen/plural

Answer (score 3):

No exception except for single-syllable words like "Schwung", "Sprung", "Dung" and composites.  Oh, and there is a children's song "In einen Harung jung und schlank, der auf dem Meeresgrunde schwamm, verliebte sich o Wunder, 'ne alte Flunder".  But that's just a quirky substitute for "Hering".